# Iterating Over a Dictionary using functions

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def big_keys(dicta,x):
    for k in dicta:
        if x < dicta.get(k,0):
            return k
```

for this function, I want it to input dicta which is a dictionary and x is int. and it should return all the k that have value more than x. however it only return one of the k and not all of them.
e.g `big_keys({"a":20 ,"b":20 ,"c":10},15)` → `["a", "b"]`
but my out put is `["a"]`

Comment: If you want to *return a list*, then somewhere you have to *create a list* and *append to it* and at the end *return the list*…

Comment: FWIW: `[k for k, v in dicta.items() if v > x]`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimum effort solution would be to gather all suitable `k` in a list and return that list:

```
def big_keys(dicta,x):
    results = []
    for k in dicta:
        if x < dicta.get(k,0):
            results.append(k)
```

However you can write that more compactly and efficient with list comprehension:

```
def big_keys(dicta, x):
    return [k for k in dicta if x < dicta[k]]
```

note that there is no need for `dicta.get(k, 0)`, as `k in dicta` is guaranteed by the fact that we're iterating over `dicta`.

EDIT: iterating over `dicta.items()` instead of calling `dicta[k]` is of course also valid; I'm not sure if one is significantly faster than the other …

EDIT: Just ran a simple `timeit` and `dicta.items()` is indeed faster